# Why I can't user another fork with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I used to use package (https://github.com/jildertmiedema/laravel-plupload) for my laravel project, but the author did not update it for laravel 7.

But I found another package (https://github.com/askippers/laravel-plupload) which was forked by another author and updated composer.json for laravel 7 supporting.

Before it my composer.json looked like that

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "jildertmiedema/laravel-plupload": "0.5.0",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

after I found the fork my composer.json became

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "jildertmiedema/laravel-plupload": "dev-master",
        ...
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/askippers/laravel-plupload"
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

But when I try to use composer update I get an error

> - jildertmiedema/laravel-plupload dev-master requires illuminate/support ^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0,
>     v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0,
>     v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0,
>     v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13,
>     v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8,
>     v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0,
>     v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].

If I try to use just

> composer require askippers/laravel-plupload

My autoloading does not work because of there is wrong folder tree which is look like this

[image]

but the right path must be

> **DIR** . '/..' . '/askippers/laravel-plupload/JildertMiedema/LaravelPlupload/src'

Comment: Did you install the latter package through composer require command or modified `composer.json`.

Comment: Also the error seems clear and concise. I would suggest you to update illuminate package

Comment: modified composer.json

Comment: The package asks me install old version of Laravel. I don't understand why because of I use fork with new version of Laravel

Comment: Okay. try a composer require as suggesed in the readme.

Comment: This package does not ask you to update whole of the laravel package but `illuminate/support` package.

Comment: Yes. But I don't have illuminate/support package in my package list. illuminate/support is a part of Laravel

Comment: Try a composer update.

Comment: I expanded the question. I tried to use composer require and composer updated

Comment: Did it break after you added this dependency?

Comment: But it successfully installed after this?

Comment: It successfully installed but I can't use the package because of there is folder with wrong tree

Comment: Are you using git in project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require": { 
    ... 
       "askippers/laravel-plupload": "dev-master", 
    ... 
},
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the forked version, just require it using `composer require askippers/laravel-plupload`. Adding the repository configuration does not change anything, as you don't want to install the **same** package from another repository, but one with **another** name - Composer itself does not know anything about this being a fork